# Ajax - Commando Load não funciona

Tags: html, ajax

Gostaria de saber porque o comando load não está carregando o arquivo header.html. PS.: Ambos estão na mesma pasta.

Arquivo: main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Showing Ajax Load Request Status in jQuery</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#box").load("header.html", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, jqXHR){
            if(statusTxt == "success"){
                alert("New content loaded successfully!");
            }
            if(statusTxt == "error"){
                alert("Error: " + jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        <h2>Click button to load new content inside DIV box</h2>
    </div>
    <button type="button">Load Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Arquivo header.html:

```
<h1>Simple Ajax Demo</h1>
<p id="hint">This is a simple example of Ajax loading.</p>
```

Comment: Não está disparando os alertas?

Comment: O alerta ERROR está disparando. Isso quer dizer que o conteúdo do arquivo header.html não está sendo colocado na DIV "box"

Comment: Qual a mensagem que mostra o alerta? O alerta possui duas variáveis que mostram exatamente o erro retornado.

Comment: [Image](https://i.postimg.cc/kMsRmPBs/img.png) - "Error: 0 error"

Comment: Aqui tá funcionando legal. [Veja aqui](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/teste2.php)